# PHP error: Undefined Index

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, file, upload

I'm newbie on Ajax and PHP.
Decided to create index.php (using ajax) and simpan.php

```
<?php
include 'koneksi.php'; //conn
$target_dir="foto/";
$target_file=$target_dir.basename($_FILES['foto']['name']); //error
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$target_file); //error
$q=$db->prepare("insert into mahasiswa values
(?,?,?,?,?)");
$param=array($_POST['nim'],$_POST['nama'],
            $_POST['alamat'],$_POST['email'],
            $_FILES['foto']['name']); //error
$q->execute($param);
if($q){
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

I'm confused it has some errors:

> Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\lat_ajax204\simpan.php on
>   line 4
>
> Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\lat_ajax204\simpan.php on
>   line 5
>
> Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\lat_ajax204\simpan.php on
>   line 10
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'foto' cannot be null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lat_ajax204\simpan.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lat_ajax204\simpan.php(11):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lat_ajax204\simpan.php on line 11

I create a mysql column in mahasiswa table for foto, the type is blob. Does it make the problem? But index.php has no error at all. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Is this when you upload a file? Could it be when the form is submitted without a file included in the form?

Comment: @Technoh Even if the form is submitted without a file, the `$_FILES` array is filled, just with `error` set to `4`.

Comment: @Technoh it happen when i clicked submit button in index page, it reload and err happened

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav please re-write and fix the code to explain how to init the var thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use isset() to check if the form is submitted.**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```
<?php
include 'koneksi.php'; //conn
if(isset($_FILES['foto'],$_POST['nim'],$_POST['nama'],$_POST['alamat'],$_POST['email'])) {
  $target_dir="foto/";
  $target_file=$target_dir.basename($_FILES['foto']['name']); //error
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$target_file); //error
  $q=$db->prepare("insert into mahasiswa values
  (?,?,?,?,?)");
  $param=array($_POST['nim'],$_POST['nama'],
              $_POST['alamat'],$_POST['email'],
              $_FILES['foto']['name']); //error
  $q->execute($param);
  if($q){
      echo "OK";
  }else{
      echo "fail";
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou, no more line of error. but data doesn't inserted to database.. can you fix it?

Comment: Hi Satria, the code snippet above is a direct answer to your question regarding undefined index errors. Why the data in not inserted in the database is out of the scope of the index errors problem.

Comment: You can ask a new question and post your HTML/PHP code to see if anyone can help you with the database problem.